# Selenium unable to login to Django LiveServerTestCase

Tags: django, selenium, testing, pytest

I'm struggling to get Selenium working with my Django project. I can (finally) get it to `get` pages during testing, but I'm unable to get it to login for some reason.

This is my (very simple) test case:

```
import pytest

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.test.client import Client

from pytest_django.live_server_helper import LiveServer
from selenium.webdriver import Remote

from users.tests.factories import UserFactory


pytestmark = pytest.mark.django_db


class TestDashboard:
    def test_site_loads(self, browser: Remote, test_server: LiveServer):
        browser.get(test_server.url)

        assert 'Welcome' in browser.title

    def test_valid_login(self, browser: Remote, test_server: LiveServer, user: settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL):
        password = 'testpassword'
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        browser.get(test_server.url + '/accounts/login/')
        browser.find_element_by_name('login').send_keys(user.email)
        browser.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)
        browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button[type="submit"]').click()
        browser.implicitly_wait(2)

        assert f'Successfully signed in as {user.username}' in browser.page_source
```

`test_site_loads` passes, `test_valid_login` fails, and if I example `browser.current_url` it's still pointing at /accounts/login/. If I look at the page source using `browser.page_source`, I can see "The e-mail address and/or password you specified are not correct." in the login form's error list.

I  have no idea why the login credentials are failing here and I can't think of anything else to look at.

Here's what I see in the `browser.page_source` (captured via a `print` just before the `assert` statement) I mentioned above:

```
<form action="/accounts/login/" class="login auth-form" method="post"> 
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="xLRQ8nZlfocyyQDlJxgLL0PUvsYLLNYNHEZ5awn8cLseQoR2XNQm4TiKOgMvcaS9"> 
<div class="alert alert-block alert-danger">
    <ul>
        <li>The e-mail address and/or password you specified are not correct.</li>
    </ul>
</div> 
<div id="div_id_login" class="form-group">
    <div class="">
        <input type="email" name="login" value="ricardosoto@gmail.com" placeholder="E-mail address" autofocus="autofocus" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_login">
    </div>
</div> 
<div id="div_id_password" class="form-group"> 
    <div class=""> 
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_password">
    </div>
</div> 
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign In</button> 
</form>
```

I've also include the relevant fixtures for the tests:

```
import environ
import pytest
import socket

from django.conf import settings

from selenium.webdriver import Remote
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

from pytest_django.live_server_helper import LiveServer

from users.tests.factories import UserFactory


env = environ.Env()


@pytest.fixture
def browser() -> Remote:
    driver = Remote(
        command_executor=env('SELENIUM_HOST', default='http://selenium:4444/wd/hub'),
        desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
    )
    yield driver
    driver.quit()


@pytest.fixture
def test_server() -> LiveServer:
    addr = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    server = LiveServer(addr)
    yield server
    server.stop()


@pytest.fixture
def user() -> settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL:
    return UserFactory()
```

Just as a sanity check, I've tried adding a couple of extra `print` statements to examine everything just prior to the `assert`:

```
    print('User email: ' + user.email)
    print('User is active? ' + str(user.is_active))
    print('Password valid? ' + str(user.check_password(password)))
    print('URL: ' +browser.current_url)
```

Gives me:

```
User email: rparsons@yahoo.com
User is active? True
Password valid? True
URL: http://172.19.0.6:44025/accounts/login/
```

I've also tried adding an extra test that bypasses Selnium, to try and isolate the issue a bit more:

```
class TestAccountLoginView:
    def test_valid(self, client, user: settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, request_factory: RequestFactory):
        password = 'password'
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        response = client.post('/accounts/login/', {'login': user.email, 'password': password})

        assert response.status_code == 302
```

This works as expected and logs me in just fine.

**Update,**

Looks like this may actually have something to do with pytest-django's LiveServer. Ignoring the `live_server` fixture, and using Django's `StaticLiveServerTestCase`, I can login just fine:

```
class TestDashboard(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.selenium = Remote(
            command_executor='http://selenium:4444/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
        )
        cls.selenium.implicitly_wait(10)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()
        super().tearDownClass()

    def test_login(self):
        get_user_model().objects.create_user(username='testuser', email='test@example.com', password='password')

        self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/accounts/login/'))
        username_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_name("login")
        username_input.send_keys('test@example.com')
        password_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_name("password")
        password_input.send_keys('password')
        self.selenium.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()

        assert 'Successful' in self.selenium.page_source
```

Not quite sure why the pytest-django's LiveServer is doing this, but at least I've got somewhere to look now.

Comment: 1. can you provide more spdcific info about that "it fails" ? 
2. after browser.get(blablabla), I would put time.sleep(3) to let the page load ( just in case ), if this doesnt help, try to change find_element_by_name to Xpath

Comment: Not sure what else to add that would help. The `test_valid_login` test fails on the assertion. If I output the `browser.page_source` that the assertion is running against, it's just the login page again with an error in the login form: "The e-mail address and/or password you specified are not correct.".

Comment: 'Successfully signed in as {}'.format(user.username) <- give this a try then

Comment: Didn't seem to make a difference. Still seeing login failures. I'll add the form I'm seeing to the question. Maybe helpful?

Comment: yeah sure + print and show us those 2 prints you want to assert

Comment: Threw in a couple extra `print` statements just above the assert. Details in the question since comments don't let me format.

Comment: Try to register the user first, to see if it works ... this looks like you are parsing a wrong password / you have wrongly written login function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193541/discussion-between-notanumber-and-stylez).

Comment: @notanumber, I am using your TestServer fixture and I got it to work to the same point to where I cannot log in users...SO I have the exact same problem now.... Have you ever figured this out? Thanks in advance

Comment: Or @StyleZ could you figure out a solution? Thanks in advance, desperate here.

Comment: @Micromegas sorry, I never did get this to work properly and due to time constraints I never had a chance to dig too much deeper into. If I do find a solution, I'll update here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! Yes if you find anything I'd really appreciate your insights. If I can solve it, I'll let you know too, but I doubt it since it's such an odd behaviour. Anyways, thanks again.

Comment: @Micromegas I am sorry too, I have not seen this post for a year and now I sadly dont remember how to even think about it :D ... But I wish you the best in searching / figuring out your answer :)

Comment: @StyleZ thank you so much for your response though! In case I figure sth out I'll let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so the problem was that I had to pass ``transactional_db`` to the fixture where I create my user. I didn't figure this out myself but asked and bountied a question here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60744437/ . I hope you can still find it useful. I couldn't have gotten this to work without your question here and using the test_server fixture. So thanks again and I hope it helps.