# Selenium login test doesn't accept pytest fixtures for login or refuses to connect

Tags: python, docker, selenium, pytest

I'm getting desperate because I can't seem to find a solution for what I thought would be used by everyone out there.

I want to test a simple login with selenium and pytest with a live_server url. According to pytest-django doc, a simple fixture called `live_server` should do the trick (https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#live-server).

Unfortunately when I pass this fixture to my test and try to visit my website with it I get:

> localhost refused to connect

for example for this:

```
    def test_selenium(self, live_server, create_staff_user_in_db):
        browser = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://selenium:4444/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME,
        )

        browser.get(live_server.url)
```

Leveraging this question [Selenium unable to login to Django LiveServerTestCase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194838/) I am trying to use a different server-fixture which then connects me and I can see my website in my VNC viewer.

```
@pytest.fixture
def test_server() -> LiveServer:
    addr = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    server = LiveServer(addr)
    yield server
    server.stop()
```

But with this I am now not able to login to my website if I create users in the db with my fixtures. Even though it seems like users are actually created. So my test now looks like:

```
  def test_selenium(self, test_server, create_staff_user_in_db):
        browser = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://selenium:4444/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME,
        )

        browser.get(f"{live_server.url}/login")
        input_username = browser.find_element_by_name('username')
        input_password = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
        input_username.send_keys('testuserstaff')
        input_password.send_keys('mypasswordstaff')
        browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="page-top"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/form/button'
        ).click()
```

And my user fixture is:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def create_staff_user_in_db():
    User = get_user_model()
    staff_user = User.objects.create_user(
        username="testuserstaff",
        password="mypasswordstaff",
    )
    staff_user.is_staff = True
    staff_user.save()

    return staff_user
```

The tests visits my login page and fails to log in. I am 100% certain that I am using the right credentials.

If I print out for debugging I also can verify that my user is in my db:

```
print(u.username) ==> testuserstaff
print(u.password) ==> igetthehashofthepassword
print(User.objects.count()) ==> 1
```

Thus I assume the db that is being created by pytest is filled with this user I pass as fixture. Now somehow my live server is either not using the db or not recognising the fixtures.

It must be connected to the live_server/test_server fixture. I would be supergrateful for any help. I feel like I am so close but I just can't seem to find out why it doesn't log in.

What else have I tried: 
1) Login in with users that are in my development db. No success. So I am wondering: What db is then be used?

2) I tried to setup pytest-selenium library. If I try to load a page I get `selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to create session`

3) I tried to work with StaticLiveServerCase, but this is not an option since I need to pass fixtures as an argument.

4) I searched everywhere on the web and cannot find anything else

Also good to know:

I am running this in a docker environment (happy to share if it helps)

So my stack is basically:
Docker, Django, Pytest, selenium

Again, would really appreciate a hand here. Thanks so much in advance

EDIT:

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: mywebsite_local_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start

  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
      - 5900:5900

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: mywebsite_production_postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
```

Comment: are you bringing up these containers on the default bridge network in docker?

Comment: Thanks for your response @akazuko... I have to admit I am a beginner when it comes to docker so I can't say which network I am using... I am not specifying any particular network. I added my docker compose file... Maybe that helps?

Comment: okay, given your compose file and the way you are trying to access selenium server i.e via "http : // selenium..." one issue is obvious. You are trying to connect to container using service name as DNS entry for the container. It works, but NOT on default network. See this for ref: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/ "Containers on the default bridge network can only access each other by IP addresses"

Comment: Add this at the end in your docker-compose file: https://gist.github.com/AkaZuko/85328ba905dca52eba58334af5908bf3 This will allow all services to come on a custom bridge network and in this network selenium would be reachable using the service name

Comment: Thank you! But when I put it on the same indentation level as version I get ``networks.default value Additional properties are not allowed ('name' was unexpected)`` and if I put it at the a same level as postgres I get ``Unsupported config option for services.networks: 'default'``

Comment: and I am running docker-compose version 1.25.4...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210264/discussion-between-akazuko-and-micromegas).

Comment: I wonder whether the user is stored in the db; can you try changing fixture signature to `def create_staff_user_in_db(transactional_db):` and see whether it helps?

Comment: _So I am wondering: What db is then be used?_ The one you have configured in the settings module you are passing via `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`.

Comment: Omg!! That did the trick!! How? Why? Oh I am so happy I was trying for weeks to get this to run! Please add an answer so you can collect the bounty! If you want you can explain why this works. I assume that the ``live_server`` fixture of django uses ``transactional_db``  automatically but that the ``test_server`` doesn't? Saved me, thanks a million!

Comment: @hoefling Your suggestions worked for OP. Please take out a moment to publish your comment as an answer to be accepted and the bounty to be rewarded.

Comment: @hoefling, sorry I forgot to address you directly in my previous comment! Thanks so much again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning the comment into an answer: by default, the tests avoid running db queries to not to slow down the test run, so `User.objects.create_user` doesn't write to database. To ensure db commits, use the `@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)` marker in tests or the `transactional_db` fixture in your fixtures:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def create_staff_user_in_db(transactional_db):
    staff_user = User.objects.create_user(...)
    ...
```

> I assume that the `live_server` fixture of django uses `transactional_db` automatically but that the `test_server` doesn't?

Exactly - `live_server` implies the transactional mode, but the custom impl of `test_server` doesn't. Explicitly requesting the `transactional_db` fixture in `test_server` should fix it:

```
@pytest.fixture
def test_server(request) -> LiveServer:
    request.getfixturevalue("transactional_db")
    ...
```

BTW if you just want to apply the live server address dynamically, you shouldn't need to define your own fixture; writing config values should suffice. Example:

```
# conftest.py

def pytest_configure(config):
    config.option.liveserver = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

This value will then be used by the builtin `live_server` fixture. Put the `conftest.py` into your project or tests root dir to make `pytest` find the hookimpl early enough for it to be applied.

Comment: fantastic answer, that gives me even more understanding and insight than your comment. Providing ``pytest_configure(config)`` works as suggested as does padding the ``transactional_db`` fixture. I think I go with the configuration option since it is cleaner and less code in my eyes. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help!